# Which software is best suitable for object detection?

Tags: python

I have a video feed and from that video I have to detect objects, particularly FOD (foreign object debris) on aircraft runways.

What software is available for that?

Comment: What OS, price? How are the videos oriented - sideways or vertical? Example pictures? And you mean an actual live feed, not stored videos? Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

In general the [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) bindings for python are the best starting point for any Computer Vision project *it is what the whole project is about after all*.

I strongly recommend reading [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/) excellent post on using [YOLO](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640) for object detection but keep in mind that for FOD detection anything that is not a fixed part of the airfield and is not an Aircraft *or possibly a service truck* is FOD so you may not need the object identification level of processing.